# How to show a div only when the results calculated?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, slideshow

I have some calculation, lets say, for example `c=a+b`
and this is done by user inputs.

I need a div to be showed in the screen with the result
(not after window loading).

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about `<div>{{c}}</div>`?

Comment: There is tremendous documents are available on net. Lets try those first

Comment: Delete your question to earn the [Peer Pressure Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide show on blur event of a and b elements

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app>
  First number: <input id="a" type="number" ng-model="a"><br>
  Second number: <input id="b" type="number" ng-model="b"><br>
  
      <div ng-show="a + b >0"> Sum  = {{a + b}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The question is about angularjs, not jquery.

Comment: this question should not even be answered but still: the condition "a + b >0" in your ng-show is non-relevent. What if he wants to add negative numbers ? Putting "a && b" in the ng-show should work.